# Errors unique to Db2 SQL queries

Tags: sql, db2

I am using [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/japanese-cities-attributes/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) to learn SQL sufficiently to pass coding interviews.

I have noticed an error in the online compiler when I run it using DB2.  In Oracle, MS MS SQL SERVER, or MySQL no error is produced.

The following code is the solution to the problem posted above.

```
SELECT * 
FROM City 
WHERE Countrycode = 'JPN';
```

It returns the following in everything except in Db2:

```
1613 Neyagawa JPN Osaka 257315 
1630 Ageo JPN Saitama 209442 
1661 Sayama JPN Saitama 162472 
1681 Omuta JPN Fukuoka 142889 
1739 Tokuyama JPN Yamaguchi 107078
```

But for some reason using DB2 it returns the solution and then an error message:

```
1613 Neyagawa JPN Osaka 257315 
1630 Ageo JPN Saitama 209442 
1661 Sayama JPN Saitama 162472 
1681 Omuta JPN Fukuoka 142889 
1739 Tokuyama JPN Yamaguchi 107078
```

> DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it returned:
> SQL0104N An unexpected token "database" was found following "k line. */ uncatalog". Expected tokens may include: "JOIN <joined_table>".
> SQLSTATE=42601

How widely used is Db2?  How can I avoid this error?

Comment: I just tried it and there was no error. Not sure why you would get that error. Try again maybe.

DB2 is widely used. In fact SQL was invented by IBM and db2 became a product in 1983.

Comment: how do you execute the query on DB2 ?  directly with DB2 command ?

Comment: you have to connect to database: db2 connect to <DATABASE NAME> ; db2 "SELECT * FROM city where   WHERE Countrycode = 'JPN'"  !! there is no ending ;

Comment: This may be specific to the web browser complier on hacker rank then.  I was just curious why it's happening there.

Comment: The DB21034E error is occurring because the command line processor (CLP) is encountering unexpected input. It mentions `*/` in the offending input, which looks a failed attempt to comment something out. Comments are handled differently depending on your OS shell and the Db2 scripting utility you're using (CLP vs. CLPPlus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error prompts when database is not cataloged. Db2 requires catalog to get the correct answer. You check if database is cataloged in the local directory and run the program. On hackerrank we cannot check the db so it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is delete the comment on the bottom in hacker rank, that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing the exact same thing, and it turned out I just needed to add the ';' at the end of the line, as the instructions state. Coming from python, I forgot